# How to run a large python script using FastAPI?

Tags: python, fastapi

Let say on start_process(), FastApi will trigger a script that will take around one-two weeks to execute.

We don't want to wait for script to complete, just trigger and let it run background.

What would be the best way to handle this kind of scenario?

for eg:

```
@app.get("/")
def start_process():
    // Trigger the script here. And let it run in background
    return {"message": "Process has been started successfully"}
```

Comment: Use `celery` or another async method of calling the long task. This is not `fastAPI` specific...but here is a quick example: https://testdriven.io/blog/fastapi-and-celery/

Comment: Maybe some task queue like celery?